# Facing Some Errors with my Python GUI Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Actually an application using Tkinter and Python and now I am facing some issues. I want that when I Choose the Button a dialog appears and it select image and then change the default avatar to the selected one but I am unable to do so , If any One have any Idea what to do in such situation it is appreciated

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage,filedialog,Label
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"D:/projects/notes app/common assets file")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

def choose_image():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Image", filetypes=[("Image Files", "*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg")])
    if file_path:
        new_avatar_image = Image.open(file_path)
        # Save the selected image to the assets directory
        new_avatar_path = relative_to_assets("selected_avatar.png")
        new_avatar_image.save(new_avatar_path)
        # Update the avatar image on the canvas with the selected image
        canvas.itemconfig(avatar, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_avatar_image))


window = Tk()

window.geometry("885x575")
window.configure(bg = "#DFD9D9")


canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#DFD9D9",
    height = 575,
    width = 885,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
canvas.create_text(
    127.0,
    63.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Add an Avatar or Profile Picture ",
    fill="#1E1E1E",
    font=("Sora Regular", 40 * -1)
)


default_avatar_path = relative_to_assets("avatar.png")
avatar_image = Image.open(default_avatar_path)
avatar_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(avatar_image)
avatar = canvas.create_image(442.0, 254.0, image=avatar_photo)


entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(
    442.5,
    404.5,
    image=entry_image_1
)
entry_1 = Entry(
    bd=0,
    bg="#A1A1A1",
    fg="#000716",
    highlightthickness=0
)
entry_1.place(
    x=201.0,
    y=384.0,
    width=483.0,
    height=39.0
)

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("next.png"))
button_1 = Button(
    image=button_image_1,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("Move to Next Page"),
    relief="flat"
)
button_1.place(
    x=725.0,
    y=508.0,
    width=134.0,
    height=43.0
)

button_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("back.png"))
button_2 = Button(
    image=button_image_2,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("Go Backwards"),
    relief="flat"
)
button_2.place(
    x=571.0,
    y=507.0,
    width=134.0,
    height=44.0
)

button_image_3 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("choose.png"))
button_3 = Button(
    image=button_image_3,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=choose_image,
    relief="flat"
)
button_3.place(
    x=565.0,
    y=384.0,
    width=129.0,
    height=41.0
)
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

This is The Complete Code of My project and I have Used Pathlib to manage the file on Cross platform like Linux and Windows
[These are the images which is being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2TVr.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function